# Something that has dependencies is a

Tags: nouns, programming

As is often the case, I got stuck while programming because I couldnt' find the right name for a variable.

I want to write an interface for a class that has dependencies, but I'm unsure about how to name it.

TL;DR:

Something that has dependencies is a ...

fill in the blank

Comment: Something that has dependencies is a dependent.

Comment: Did you mean dependant?

Comment: You say dependant, I say dependent:  http://grammarist.com/spelling/dependant-dependent/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something that has dependencies is a **dependant**.

This is the situation explained:

> Whenever a class A uses another class or interface B, then A depends
>   on B. A cannot carry out it's work without B, and A cannot be reused
>   without also reusing B. In such a situation the class A is called the
>   "**dependant**" and the class or interface B is called the "dependency". **A
>   dependant depends on its dependencies**.

Source:
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/ood/understanding-dependencies.html#whatis

Answer (score 1):

*head*.  The term comes from dependency grammar, where grammatical constituents are taken to have a head word, which determines the central properties of the constituent, and other subsidiary constituents.  E.g., the nominal properties of a noun phrase are due to its head word being a noun, and subsidiary constituents, i.e. *dependencies*, are determiner, adjective, prepositional phrase, relative clause.  When a noun. e.g. "man", occurs with such a dependent, e.g. a determiner "the", within a noun phrase, e.g. "the man", one says this dependency of the head has been *satisfied*.

There is lots of disagreement about which part of a grammatical constituent is the head (if any) and which parts are dependents.

Answer (score 0):

**"main source"** comes to mind.  I would also suggest **"main office"** and **"headquarters"**

> - headquarters (noun) "a place from which something (such as a business or a military action) is controlled or directed" [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/headquarters)